# improving the performance of a select query on a large table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a large table & am using SQL Server 2017. The table contains 4 columns shown below.

```
 Column name     Data type
 IndexDate       date
 Code            nvarchar(20)
 Sedol           nvarchar(7)
 Wgt             float
```

The table contains daily data for different stock market indices (eg S&P 500, Russell 1000, FTSE 100 etc) and the weight of each stock in the index. So typically daily about 16,000 rows of data are added to the database.

The data starts from just before the year 2000. Currently there are approx 60 million rows.

Recently people have wanted to query the table and have a structure like below,

```
    Sedol     06-03-2019    06-04-2019   06-05-2019 ...
    ABC       0.03          0.0301       0.031
    MNB       0.015         0.0147       0.0145
    LPK       0.02          0.0201       0.0201
```

So I created a dynamic stored procedure which makes use of the pivot function. Which looks like below. It takes three parameters, 2 dates for the date range and another for the index code.

```
 declare @dates nvarchar(max) = ''

select @dates = @dates + QUOTENAME(date) + ',' 
    from DVLP_QES_MS.dbo.DateDimension where date >= @dateFrom and date <= @dateTo and IsWeekend = 0
set @dates = SUBSTRING(@dates, 1, len(@dates) - 1)

declare @q nvarchar(max) = ''


 set @q = 'select * from
(
    select Sedol, wgt, w.Date 
    from tblBMWeights w right join tblDates d on w.Date = d.Date
    where Code = ''' + @bm + ''' and d.IsWeekend = 0 and d.Date >= ''' + convert(varchar(10), @dateFrom, 110) + ''' and d.Date <= ''' + convert(varchar(10), @dateTo, 110) + '''
)source pivot(max(wgt) for Date in (' + @dates + ' )) as pvt order by Sedol'

exec(@q)
```

Generally this seemed to work, querying 6 months of data takes about 2 seconds approx. However there is now a demand for querying the data further back.

18 months takes 14 seconds approx
30 months takes 40 seconds approx
3 years takes 1 minutes approx.

I have created indices on my tables to help improve the efficiency of the queries. My question is how should my table be structured and how can I improve the performance so that 3 years of data doesn't take 1 minute to query? Obviously other people have much bigger tables, how do they manage to deal with tables that have over 100 million rows? Should I have multiple tables?

I have saved the execution plan but can't seem to attach it to this post.

**Update**

This is the link for [my plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r19-9h8AV)

The three indices

1st)

```
 NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_tblBenchmarkWeights_CodeDate_Sedol] ON [dbo]. 
 [tblBenchmarkWeights]
 (
    [Code] ASC,
    [Date] ASC
 )
 INCLUDE (  [Sedol]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] GO
```

2nd)

```
  NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_tblBenchmarkWeights_CodeDateSedolWgt] ON [dbo]. 
 [tblBenchmarkWeights]
  (
     [Code] ASC,
     [Date] ASC
  )
  INCLUDE (     [Sedol],[Wgt]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] GO
```

3rd)

```
 NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_tblBenchmarkWeights_DateSedol] ON [dbo]. 
 [tblBenchmarkWeights]
 (
    [Date] ASC
 )
  INCLUDE (     [Sedol]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] GO
```

Last index on my date table

```
  NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_DateDimension_IsWeekendDate] ON [dbo].[DateDimension]
 (
    [IsWeekend] ASC,
    [Date] ASC
  )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] GO
```

Comment: You can use [this](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) to post the execution plan. Have you heard of parameterized queries? This appears to be wide open to sql injection, not good.

Comment: Questions: what is "@dates" and "@bm"? I suspect bm is a single ticker/sedol?

Comment: And how about table definitions including indexes of the two tables? Some sample data would help also. You know, the kinds of things that let people recreate queries.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz I have updated my post to include all of my stored procedure so you can see what dates & bm are. bm is an index code so say for S&P500 its SP500

Comment: @SeanLange thanks for the link to post my plan, have attached the link. I have also copied the definitions of my indices. I will try getting data as well, just need to create some data as there is licence restrictions on the data

Comment: Don't post real data, use dummy data that represents the issue.

Comment: Holy cowabunga!!! You are doing a dynamic pivot with over 1,000 columns. What do you expect to happen with performance? What is this used for?

Comment: fyi using desc in indexes sometimes is also faster if your queries are concerned more about recent data

Comment: @SeanLange its to get the data in a time series format. Guessing from your response this shouldn't be done like this?

Comment: I am not saying it shouldn't...but I am saying it is going to be slower than molasses in Alaska in January. How is a query with over 1,000 column useful for anything in the first place?

Comment: haha like that description. The query is called from within matlab which works with matrices. Guessing it should just select all the required data then sort it into this shape within matlab

Comment: @SeanLange rather than doing a pivot I just did a simple select query, select Date, Sedol, Wgt 
from tblBenchmarkWeights
where Date >= '2016-06-04' and Date <= '2019-06-04' and Code = '990100' so 3 years of data and that still takes 40 seconds & that is using a index

Answer (score -1):

> To improve the select query performance follow the below constraints :
>
> Select only the fields you required ,
>   Create indexes for fast table seek quickly instead instead of relying on table scan,
>   Use EXISTS instead of IN to check existence of data,
>   Use WITH (NOLOCK) table hint on Select and Joins while querying the data from any table in order to avoid deadlock,
>   Use try catch block to avoid deadlock condition,
>   Use appropriate datatype on column fields ,
>   Use schema name before SQL Objectname,
>   Use transaction in query

Comment: There are some good points in here. However there are also several that are not a good idea as a blanket statement and some that are just flatout terrible advice. NOLOCK is NOT a performance tool. It can improve performance but it comes with a big price tag. Things like missing and/or duplicate rows is an example of the "features". But more than anything this doesn't even make an attempt at answering the question.